# Counting natural numbers in a set $\{\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!k}:k=1,2,...n-1,n\}$, for every $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Define a (set-valued) function $ n \to \{\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!k}:k=1,2,...n-1,n\}$. Now let $f$ be a function that counts the number of natural numbers in the set $\{\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!k}:k=1,2,...n-1,n\}$.

A question is: Is $f(n)=1$ for only a finite number of values of $n$?

Here, we study, for each natural number $n$, a set $\{\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!k}:k=1,2,...n-1,n\}$ and seek to determine is there a finite number of natural numbers $n$ for which only the first term is a natural number.

Also, investigations of values of function $f$ are really welcomed, it would be nice to see, is, for example, $f(n)$ in OEIS, for some relatively small number of first values of $f$?

I expect a finite number of natural numbers for which $f(n)=1$ because it seems to me that, although there will be much cancellations in calculation of a number $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, there should be enough richness in a structure of $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ that allows $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!k}$ to be a natural number for some $k \in \{1,2,...,n\} \setminus \{1\}$

Comment: Just a small heads-up: this could be (IMHO) much more cleanly written as 'let $f(n)$ be the number of $k\leq n$ such that $k|{n\choose k}$. Are there infinitely many $n$ with $f(n)=1$?'. There's not much to be gained by talking about the set if all you're doing is counting it, and '$k|{n\choose k}$' is not just more concise but also just sounds better (to my mathematical ear) than '$\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!k}$ is an integer'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, the question can be put in that form, it is just a matter of style.

Comment: Also, a quick search using the first ten rows (OEIS is a public resource; you could have checked this as easily yourself) yields https://oeis.org/A081372 which gives more terms but little additional information; plugging in the sequence of only those $n$ with $f(n)=1$ doesn't yield anything.

Comment: It suffices to prove it for squarefree $n$, because if $p^2$ divides $n$, then one can take $k = p$.

Comment: More generally, if $n \equiv a \pmod{p^2}$ for some prime $p < n$ with $a < p$, then one can take $k = p$.

Comment: I have checked with a computer and, unless I made a mistake, the only $n \le 5\cdot10^5$ for which $f(n) = 1$ are $1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 15, 22, 23, 95$.

Comment: @Woett I think there is no mistake, it corresponds exactly with OEIS link that Steven gave.